# React JS page went blank after I used a setState() in my functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

The code was alright before I tried to used the setState function which is setcategory and setvalue in this code but after I did this my react page went blank. What went wrong and how should I fix it?

````
import Employee_card from './Employee_card'
import '../styles/home.css'
import {
  Link,
  useSearchParams
} from 'react-router-dom'

const Employee_dir:React.FC <props> = (employes) => {

  const [category, setcategory] = useState("")
  const [value, setvalue] = useState("")

 let [searchParams]=useSearchParams();
  
  if(searchParams){
    setcategory(searchParams.get('category')!)
    setvalue(searchParams.get('value')!)
  }

return (
    <div>
         Some code here which is alright
    <div/>
  )
}```

export default Employee_dir
````

Comment: Hmm interesting. I don't know if there's enough info here to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap it around a `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(searchParams){
    setcategory(searchParams.get('category')!)
    setvalue(searchParams.get('value')!)
  }

}, [searchParams])
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is the causing this issue

```
    if(searchParams){
    setcategory(searchParams.get('category')!)
    setvalue(searchParams.get('value')!)
  }
```

Here an infinite render loop will happen if searchParams is true. (state update in react will cause the component code to execute again(re-render)).
To avoid this you can wrap it in a useEffect block,

```
useEffect(()=> {
    if(searchParams){
    setcategory(searchParams.get('category')!)
    setvalue(searchParams.get('value')!)
  }
}, [searchParams])
```

Here the useEffect block will only execute (state updation of category and value) if searchParams value changes